# Merge and aggregate two columns SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with `id`, `name` and `score` and I am trying to extract the top scoring users. Each user may have multiple entries, and so I wish to SUM the score, grouped by user.

I have looked into `JOIN` operations, but they seem to be used when there are two separate tables, not with two 'views' of a single table.

The issue is that if the `id` field is present, the user will not have a `name`, and vice-versa.

A minimal example can be found at the following link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce0629/11

Essentially, I have the following data:

```
id    name    score
---   -----   ------
1     ''      15
4     ''      20
NULL  'paul'   8
NULL  'paul'  11
1     ''      13
4     ''      17
NULL  'simon'  9
NULL  'simon' 12
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
id/name     score
--------    ------
4           37
1           28
'simon'     21
'paul'      19
```

I can group by `id` easily, but it treats the NULLs as a single field, when really they are two separate users.

`SELECT id, SUM(score) AS total FROM posts GROUP BY id ORDER by total DESC;`

```
id    score
---   ------
NULL  40
4     37
1     28
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The target environment for this query is in Hive. Below is the query and output looking only at the `id` field:

```
hive> SELECT SUM(score) as total, id FROM posts WHERE id is not NULL GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10;
...
OK
29735   87234
20619   9951
20030   4883
19314   6068
17386   89904
13633   51816
13563   49153
13386   95592
12624   63051
12530   39677
```

Running the query below gives the exact same output:

```
hive> select coalesce(id, name) as idname, sum(score) as total from posts group by coalesce(id, name) order by total desc limit 10;
```

Running the following query using the new calculated column name `idname` gives an error:

```
hive> select coalesce(id, name) as idname, sum(score) as total from posts group by idname order by total desc limit 10;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:83 Invalid table alias or column reference 'idname': (possible column names are: score, id, name)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using Apache Hive, though don't know which DBMS it falls under

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` looks numeric.  In some databases, using `coalesce()` on a numeric and a string can be a problem.  In any case, I would suggesting being explicit about the types:

```
select coalesce(cast(id as varchar(255)), name) as id_name,
       sum(score) as total
from posts
group by id_name
order by total desc;
```

Comment: I believe that Hive uses "interesting" scope rules, and that as such it will prefer to use `GROUP BY id_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a COALESCE to get the non-NULL value of either column:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(id, name) AS id
    , SUM(score) AS total 
FROM 
    posts 
GROUP BY 
    COALESCE(id, name)
ORDER by total DESC;
```

Comment: It should be COALESCE(id,name) instead of  COALESCE(name, id)

Comment: @GauravS - Thanks :) Fixed it

Comment: Your answer works in the minimal example I provided, but not in Hive, which is my target. Apologies, the `hive` tag was only added after the question was posted.

Comment: @Matthew I believe that Hive uses "interesting" scope rules, and that as such it will prefer to use `GROUP BY id`.  *(Or, even better, use a different alias for the calculated column, such as `COALESCE(id, name) AS id_name` along with `GROUP BY id_name`)*

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for that. I tried using a new name for the calculated column, but get `Invalid table alias or column reference`. The result using the answer above is the same as `SELECT SUM(score) as total, id FROM posts WHERE id is not NULL GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10;`

Comment: @matthew - Update your question with this, and include the full and exact query you executed along with the error message  *(Don't put code in comments unless you have no alternative.)*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT new_id, SUM(score) FROM 
    (SELECT coalesce(id,name) new_id, score FROM posts)o 
GROUP BY new_id ORDER by total DESC;
```